# "Force Dark Mode for Web Contents" in Google Chrome/Chromium using command line switch(es)

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, chromium, dark-mode

I trying to enable dark mode for web content based on time of day.
However I can not enable it using command line switches.

Nothing of that works for me:

```
--dark --force-dark-mode --blink-settings=inversion_method=cielab_based,image_behavior=selective,text_lightness_threshold=150,background_lightness_threshold=205
```

Is there any possible way to enable it using command line switches?

[Force Dark Mode for Web Contents flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xup8i.png)

Answer (score 5):

There is actually a way to set whatever option of the flag you want to use.
So, for "Force Dark Mode for Web Contents" it goes like this:

> 1. Enabled:

```
--enable-features=WebContentsForceDark
```

> 2. Enabled with simple HSL-based inversion:

```
 --enable-features=WebContentsForceDark:inversion_method/hsl_based/image_behavior/none/text_lightness_threshold/256/background_lightness_threshold/0
```

> 3. Enabled with simple CIELAB-based inversion:

```
 --enable-features=WebContentsForceDark:inversion_method/cielab_based/image_behavior/none/text_lightness_threshold/256/background_lightness_threshold/0
```

> 4. Enabled with simple RGB-based inversion:

```
--enable-features=WebContentsForceDark:inversion_method/rgb_based/image_behavior/none/text_lightness_threshold/256/background_lightness_threshold/0
```

> 5. Enabled with selective image inversion:

```
--enable-features=WebContentsForceDark:inversion_method/cielab_based/image_behavior/selective/text_lightness_threshold/256/background_lightness_threshold/0
```

> 6. Enabled with selective inversion of non-image elements:

```
 --enable-features=WebContentsForceDark:inversion_method/cielab_based/image_behavior/none/text_lightness_threshold/150/background_lightness_threshold/205
```

> 7. Enabled with selective inversion of everything:

```
 --enable-features=WebContentsForceDark:inversion_method/cielab_based/image_behavior/selective/text_lightness_threshold/150/background_lightness_threshold/205
```

> 8. Disabled:

```
 --disable-features=WebContentsForceDark
```

This was tested on Chrome Stable: Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (64-bit) and on Chromium: Version 92.0.4480.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit)

After setting a flag, you can check it out if it is used by going to chrome://version/, in the "Command Line" field.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/x5xrFgYiDuE
However looks like there is not way to specify exact flag value.

Lily Chen wrote:

> Try --enable-features=WebContentsForceDark
>
> The params for each of the modes are listed here:
> https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/about_flags.cc;l=431-465;drc=5ba77dad98cf94506cf3700f9e12fcdc65fadfb6
> defined here:
> https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/common/features.cc;l=342-389;drc=7c57ca1441dba6c5113af561692e88e6c33a6ba8
>
> You can specify the params for each group via command line using
> --force-fieldtrial-params: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:components/variations/variations_switches.cc;l=22-30;drc=c3ecfbb8149e2b8843bfaf0489e4cd4404c18adb
>
> And then you can force yourself into a particular group via command
> line using --force-fieldtrials:
> https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:base/base_switches.cc;l=33-41;drc=12cd16ac3a46001b853793828f67e9cd6ffc7606
>
> You'll have to play around with the syntax (it's pretty
> tricky/annoying), but that should get you started.